Mouse controls inverted when player is upside down (Unity)
I am creating a space game in which the player can be fully rotated, axis independent. No up or down. However, whenever the player is upside down, the mouse controls are inverted. Here is the current code:
Quaternion yAxis = Quaternion.AngleAxis(pitch, Vector3.right);
Quaternion xAxis = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yaw, Vector3.up);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, xAxis * yAxis, drag * Time.deltaTime);

And heres what I had previously, which worked but I couldn't lerp for the smooth feel.
//transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Mathf.DeltaAngle(pitchOld, pitch), Space.Self);
//transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Mathf.DeltaAngle(yawOld, yaw), Space.Self);

I also tried this solution and lerping pitch & yaw, but that essentially just slowed down the look rotations instead of smoothing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need any more information just ask. Thank you!

You'd better post the mouse control code as well, not just the code related to rotation.

Your xAxis and yAxis rotations are relative to the worldspace Vector3.right and Vector3.up, I'm assuming it should be based on the camera/player's right and up instead?
